# How to count an hourly average number of persons using Hive?

Tags: sql, hive

I have this data in a table `my_table`:

```
person_id         datetime
1                 2017-03-02 18:06:20
1                 2017-03-02 18:05:10
1                 2017-04-01 18:04:09
1                 2017-03-02 19:06:50
1                 2017-04-01 19:07:22
2                 2017-03-03 18:09:15
2                 2017-05-03 19:07:05
2                 2017-05-03 20:19:08
```

I need to count the number of persons (non-unique) per hour. The problem is that I should get averaged counts (averaged over days).

Imagine that today there are 10 visitors between 18:00 and 19:00, while yesterday there were 5 visitors in the same timeframe. So, what is the average number of visitors over these two days? (10 + 5)/2 = 15 / 2 = 7.5

I expect this result:

```
person_id   HOUR   HOURLY_AVG_COUNT
1           18     1.5
1           19     1
1           20     0
2           18     1
2           19     1
2           20     1
```

I wrote the following query in Hive, but it calculates total number of persons per hour over all days:

```
SELECT person_id, HOUR(datetime), count(*) 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY person_id, HOUR(datetime) 
ORDER BY person_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select      person_id
           ,hour
           ,avg (hourly_cnt)    as hourly_avg_count

from       (select      person_id                       
                       ,hour (datetime)     as hour
                       ,count(*)            as hourly_cnt 

            from        my_table 

            group by    person_id
                       ,hour (datetime) 
                       ,date (datetime)
            ) t

group by    person_id
           ,hour

order by    person_id
           ,hour
;
```

---

```
+-----------+------+------------------+
| person_id | hour | hourly_avg_count |
+-----------+------+------------------+
|         1 |   18 | 1.5              |
|         1 |   19 | 1                |
|         2 |   18 | 1                |
|         2 |   19 | 1                |
|         2 |   20 | 1                |
+-----------+------+------------------+
```

Comment: In this case I will get 4 columns, including a date: person_id, date, hour, count. I should get just 3 columns: person_in,hour,hourly_avg_count.

Comment: You're welcome. P.s. please note that this solution does not create `0` hourly_avg_count  lines. There is no problem doing it but it will make the query more complicated and less efficient.

Comment: Ok, no problem, I do further calculations using Python and Pandas.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can use `count(distinct)` to get the average:

```
SELECT person_id, HOUR(datetime),
       COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(datetime))
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY person_id, HOUR(datetime) 
ORDER BY person_id;
```

Note:  This does not count days with no values.  Your question does not explain what to do in that case.

Comment: No, that would not give the expected result.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . You were right.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: @Dinosaurius . . . Not so fast.  Test it first.  Hive (at least earlier versions) did a lousy job of implementing `COUNT(DISTINCT)` (basically, it used a single reducer).  For a handful of rows, this is fine.  If you have large data, Dudu's answer may have much better performance.

Comment: Let me test it.

Comment: I get `None` values in the last column that is supposed to be an hourly average count.